# How to remove hyperlink on my text

Tags: hyperlink

Why does my all my text getting a hyperlink onti? here's the pic of it

[image]

Here's the html

```
<div class="container">
<header>

    <div id="logo"><h1>Rodel DY</h1></div>
<ul class="nav_menu">
    <li id="homeli"><a href="index.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
    <li id="aboutli"><a href="about.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li id="contactli"><a href="contact.html">FAQS</li>
</ul>
```

And here's where my text getting a hyperlink

```
    </header>
```

```
        <section >
        MY TEXT IS HYPERLINK!

    </section>
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your last `a` tag:

```
<li id="homeli"><a href="index.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
<li id="aboutli"><a href="about.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
<li id="contactli"><a href="contact.html">FAQS</li>
```

Note the missing `</a>` after "FAQS". Browsers tend to be rather lenient with syntax errors and just *do their thing* (in this case: treat everything after it as hyperlink), but an [HTML markup validator](https://validator.w3.org/) would have told you.